# What is wrong with this SQL statement - error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT `exp_channel_titles`.`entry_id` 
FROM (`exp_channel_titles`) 
JOIN `exp_category_posts` ON `exp_channel_titles`.`entry_id` = `exp_category_posts`.`entry_id` 
WHERE `exp_category_posts`.`cat_id` IS NULL 
  AND `exp_channel_titles`.`channel_id` IN (2) 
  AND `exp_channel_titles`.`entry_id` NOT IN ()
```

The error is:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

It highlights the `)` at the end of:

```
From (`exp_channel_titles`)
```

If I remove the `()` I get the same error however it is highlighting the `)` at the end of

```
.`channel_id` IN (2)
```

Comment: You can't have an empty IN clause: `entry_id NOT IN ()`

Comment: Yep... This SQL statement is autogenerated... I removed the entire line manually and it seems to work. Seems strange that that would cause the error, or at least that the error would appear on the first line.

Comment: If you create an answer I will approve it!

Comment: Demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c3e0/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have an empty IN clause like this `entry_id NOT IN ()`. If you can't remove that condition from your query then you could fill it with values like `0` that are not content of you `entry_id` column

```
entry_id NOT IN (0)
```